# Using multi-table join with EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to search the database for the following result:

```cs
public class PesquisaM1Dto
{
    public ColaboradorDto Colaborador { get; set; }
    public EmpresaDto Empresa { get; set; }
    public IReadOnlyList<ValorDto> Valor { get; set; }
    public IReadOnlyList<SetorDto> Setor { get; set; }

    public PesquisaM1Dto() { }
}
```

I'm trying with the following code:

```cs
var result = _dbContext.Empresas
                .Join(
                    _dbContext.Colaboradores,
                    empresa => empresa.Id,
                    colaborador => colaborador.IdEmpresa,
                    (empresa, colaborador) => new
                    {
                        colaborador,
                        empresa,
                    }
                )
                .Join(
                    _dbContext.Setores,
                    combinedEntry => combinedEntry.empresa.Id,
                    setor => setor.Id,
                    (combinedEntry, setor) => new
                    {
                        colaborador = combinedEntry.colaborador,
                        empresa = combinedEntry.empresa,
                        setores = setor
                    }
                )
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(res => res.colaborador.Id == idColaborador && res.empresa.Id == idEmpresa);
```

But I can't return a list of Sectors or Values.

Comment: Could you send your Entities, please

Comment: Why aren't you using Navigation Properties?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use EF relations? The concept is simple and can save you time in development and scale your system.

I assume each of the models in `PesquisaM1` have their own tables.

Update the Pesquisa model to include the relations:

```
public class PesquisaM1
{
    public PesquisaM1() { }
    public PesquisaM1()
    {
        Valors = new HashSet<Valor>();
        Setors = new HashSet<Setor>();
    }
    
    [Key]
    [Column("PesquisaM1Id")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid PesquisaM1Id { get; set; }
    
    public virtual Colaborador Colaborador { get; set; }
    public virtual Empresa Empresa { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Valor> Valors { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Setor> Setores { get; set; }
}
```

How to add relations an PesquisaM1 entity:

```
// Get the entity from db so that changes can be tracked.
var pesquisaM1 = await _dbContext.PesquisaM1Table
            .FirstAsync(x => x.PesquisaM1Id == pesquisaM1Id);

pesquisaM1.Colaborador = myColaborador;
pesquisaM1.Empresa = myEmpresa;
pesquisaM1.Valors.Add(myValor1);
pesquisaM1.Setores.Add(mySetor1);

await _dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Query the data for `PesquisaM1` with it's relation without the need of using join.

```
var result = _dbContext.PesquisaM1Table
                .Include(x => x.Colaborador)
                .Include(x => x.Empresa)
                .Include(x => x.Valors)
                .Include(x => x.Setores)
                .FirstAsync(x => x.PesquisaM1Id == pesquisaM1Id);

// eg. result.Setores will contain the list of setor
```